# Given $f(−5)=−4$ and $f(5)=2$ find the linear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

With this information I am to find the linear equation:
$f(−5)=−4$ and $f(5)=2$

The solution is provided as $y = \frac{3}{5}x-1$ however I arrived at $y = \frac{7}{10}x - \frac{3}{2}$

Here is my working:

Using these points, find the equation: (-5,-4)(5, 2)

the slope m:
$m = \frac{y1-y}{x1-x}$ = $\frac{2+5}{5+5}$ = $\frac{7}{10}$

Now that I have m, plug the values of one of the pairs into the linear function form to find b:
$y = mx + b$

$2 = \frac{7}{10}(5) + b$

$\frac{7}{10}(5) + b = 2$

$\frac{7}{2} + b = 2$ #7/10 * 5 = 7/2

$b = 2 - \frac{7}{2}$

$b = -\frac{3}{2}$

=> $y = \frac{7}{10}x + \frac{3}{2}$

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at $y = \frac{3}{5}x-1$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you made a mistake in the step below:

“Using these points, find the equation: (-5,-4)(5, 2)”

You should calculate 2-(-4)

Answer (score 1):

Point-slope form for the line might be a bit easier:

$$y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$$

$$m = \dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} = \dfrac{2-(-4)}{5-(-5)} = \dfrac{3}{5}$$

$$y-2 = \dfrac{3}{5}(x-5)$$

$$y = \dfrac{3}{5}x-1$$